# Can BaggingClassifier manually define multiple base_estimator in Sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

I'm trying to use BaggingClassifier from Sklearn to define multiple base_estimator. From my understanding, something would be similar to this.

```
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=[SVC(), DecisionTreeClassifier()], n_estimators=3, random_state=0)
```

But BaggingClassifier here doesn't take a list as its base_estimator.
I assume I can switch to `StackingRegressor(estimators=)` to define multiple estimators manually. But it will be a pain to list out, for example 100 estimators, no mentioning there will be many permutations and combinations of the base estimators.
Can you help me understand how to define multiple base_estimator in sklearn.BaggingClassifier?

Comment: Do you need the subsampling that bagging applies, or would simply *combining* the outputs of multiple classifiers be sufficient? If it's the latter, a [`VotingClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) ensemble does something closer to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass one estimator to `base_estimator`. The whole idea behind `BaggingBlassifier` is to train **one** model on random samples of the training data in an attempt to reduce its variance.

If you need two or more estimators, each one of them trained on random subsets of data, I suggest two different options:

1. Create your own voting process from two separate bagging classifiers
2. Train two different `BaggingClassifiers` and pass them to `sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier`.